# How to stop the text under Images of Pure Grid Div from getting Squashed

Tags: html, css, yui-pure-css

I'm using the CSS pure grid class to make a grid of images and placing a text label below each one. However, this is not working out because the text is getting squashed (see the image below):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="pure-g" style="margin-top:90px; margin-left:200px">

      <div class="pure-u-lg-1-4 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-sm-1" style="margin-right:50px">
          <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="sample_image.jpg" width=200px>
            <center>
              <span class="caption" style="color:black" > <br> My Text Under Image</span>
          </center>
        <br>
      </div>
```

Comment: `<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-lg-1-4">` is enough. The first class handles the small screen size. No need to use the pure-u-sm-1 class here. You also need to close your <a> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you including the necessary CSS file for [pure responsive grids](https://purecss.io/grids/#pure-responsive-grids)?

In your code, there was a missing ending for the `a` and `div` tags. Everything works after closing those tags:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/grids-responsive-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="pure-g" style="margin-top:90px; margin-left:200px">
  <div class="pure-u-lg-1-4 pure-u-md-1-2 pure-u-sm-1" style="margin-right:50px">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="sample_image.jpg" width=200px>
            <center>
              <span class="caption" style="color:black" > <br> My Text Under Image</span>
          </center>
        <br>
        </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The addition of the CSS file for pure responsive grids fixed it